# IF -operator error when implementing archive calendar in template (Django)

Tags: python, html, django, templates, archive

I'm trying to implement an archive with calender months but I'm not sure of how to implement it in my template and I'm getting an operationerror; Errormessage;  no such function: IF. Any help is greatly appriciated.

```
def view_calendar(request):


date_from='2015-05-01'
date_to='2015-05-31'

year=2015
month=5

where = '%(year)s >= YEAR(date_from) AND IF(%(year)s > YEAR(date_from), \
 IF(%(month)s > MONTH(date_from), %(month)s >= MONTH(date_from), %(month)s < MONTH(date_from)), \
 IF(%(month)s < MONTH(date_from), %(month)s < MONTH(date_from), %(month)s >= MONTH(date_from))) \
 AND %(year)s <= YEAR(date_to) \
 AND %(month)s <= MONTH(date_to)' % \
 {'year': year, 'month': month}
calender = Topic.objects.extra(where=[where])

print may, "M"

return render(request,"topic_index_fe.html", {'calender': calender})
```

in template

```
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 blog-sidebar">

          <div class="sidebar-module">

          <h3>Archive</h3>

          <ol class="list-unstyled">
            #print calender 
               {{ calender}}

              <li><a href="#">May 2015 </a></li>
              <li><a href="#">April 2015</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">March 2015</a></li>

          </ol>

          </div>
          <div class="sidebar-module">

          </div>
        </div><!-- /.blog-sidebar -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're specifying a SQL `WHERE` clause, you need to write valid SQL.  There's no `IF` statement in standard SQL, hence the error.  You probably want to look into the SQL `CASE` statement.

I can't really tell what you're trying to achieve with all those `IF` statements, can you provide an explanation of what the `WHERE` clause is trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm following the answer in this SO post; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488105/if-operator-error-when-implementing-archive-calendar-in-template-django/30488524#30488524, is there another way I can implement this?

Comment: to be honest, me neither, I tried this implementation but would it be sufficient to use only the AND statements?